# Why does this print the message twice per iteration?

Tags: c, while-loop

```
            char yes_no = 'z';
            int i = 0;
            while ( ( yes_no != 'y' ) && ( yes_no != 'n')  )
            {
                read( 0, &yes_no, 1 );
                printf("%dA file already exists at your write location. Over    write? (y/n)\n", i++);
            }
```

Output looks like this:

```
0A file already exists at your write location. Overwrite? (y/n)
1A file already exists at your write location. Overwrite? (y/n)
a
2A file already exists at your write location. Overwrite? (y/n)
3A file already exists at your write location. Overwrite? (y/n)
```

...etc.

Why would it go through the loop twice instead of waiting for user input every time?

Comment: Why don't you run this through the debugger and find out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you enter one letter and hit enter it puts `'a\n'` into the stream.  By reading 1 byte out of that you're still left with `'\n'` in the stream, thus next time you call `read()`, it reads the `'\n'` instead of blocking and waiting for user input. You need to discard the `'\n'` that's left in the stream.

Comment: great, i just changed read bytes to 2 and it worked.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because if you are entering ,,y'' and pressing enter, you are putting string "y\n" in the buffer-those are two characters and your program attempts to read both of them.

Answer (score 0):

You should show us more code. (when you print `a`?) I guess that you enter also newlines, so you going back to the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hunch, but because the data you enter is "a\n" and not just "a". So in the first loop read blocks because there is not data. You enter "a" and then press enter. The loop prints the error message and then loops around again. However, this time there is a still the newline character in the buffer and this is read without read ever asking for input again. And then on the third time the buffer is exhausted and read blocks again, waiting for more input.